# Strings Formatting and Kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

The following code works correctly:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
if 'fruit' in kwargs:
    print('my fruit of choice is {}'.format(kwargs['fruit']))
else:
    print('No Fruit Here')
myfunc(fruit = 'apple', veggie = 'lettuce)
```

The following code returns an error:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
if 'fruit' in kwargs:
    print(f'my fruit of choice is {fruit}')
else:
    print('No Fruit Here')
myfunc(fruit = 'apple', veggie = 'lettuce)
```

Returns: NameError: name 'fruit' is not defined

How would I format it correctly? And also, why isn't it working the way I am trying? Is it because of **kwargs?

Thank you for any help and explaining.

Comment: The name `fruit` does not exist in either case.  It's a string key of `kwargs`.  If `kwargs['fruit']` worked in the first case, why not try `print(f'my fruit of choice is {kwargs["fruit"]}')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, it should be `kwargs['fruit']` because `kwargs` is a `dict` containing all the function's parameters

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    if 'fruit' in kwargs:
        print(f"my fruit of choice is {kwargs['fruit']}")
    else:
        print('No Fruit Here')
myfunc(fruit = 'apple', veggie = 'lettuce')
#{'fruit': 'apple', 'veggie': 'lettuce'}
#my fruit of choice is apple
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the two cases are not equivalent.  In the first case:

```
print('my fruit of choice is {}'.format(kwargs['fruit']))
```

You are referring to the object `kwargs['fruit']`, which exists.  This would translate to an f-string of:

```
print(f'my fruit of choice is {kwargs["fruit"]}')
```

In your second case, the f-string is equivalent to:

```
print('my fruit of choice is {}'.format(fruit))
```

Which would give you the same error, because the object named `fruit` does not exist.

This is because your function uses variable amount of `kwargs`, which essentially create a `dict` named `kwargs` for your function to refer to locally.  If however you had created your function as:

```
def myfunc(fruit=None, veggie=None, **kwargs):
```

Then the names `fruit` and `veggie` would be known to your function locally, in addition to undefined keyword arguments in the `kwargs` dict.